# Warnings of R. Chaim Vital

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah

I read in related questions that R. 'Haim Vital lists in his introduction to Ets 'Haim 20 conditions regarding whether one is fit to learn pnimiut. However, I cannot find such a list in the book itself. I'd like a precise source, preferably with a link. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works? And also since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The list you are looking for seems to be towards the end of his introductions, in the paragraph beginning וצריך להתרחק (page 23 in [this edition](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14183&st=&pgnum=29)). He lists 10 things not to do and 10 things to do before learning this subject. There are other conditions mentioned, but only those 20 are in a numbered list.

Comment: It's cited in the second part of Shomer emunim

Comment: If you read from page 21, column 2 in your link to Eitz Chaim, you see that it states these introductions paraphrased here from Rabbi Chaim Vital were found in Sefer Pri Eitz Chaim and were only paraphrasing introductions which were taught by the Ari z”l which he received via Ruach HaKodesh directly from Eliyahu HaNavi.